# Finding the runtime of a recursive 'Generating Parenthesis' algorithm

Tags: python, performance, recursion, time-complexity

I wrote up a solution to [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/generate-parentheses/) for generating different valid combinations of parenthesis. I'm having trouble understanding the runtime of my algorithm. Here's the code:

```
class Solution:
    def generateParenthesis(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
        resultList = []
        comboList = []
        self.generate(resultList, n, comboList, 0, 0)
        return resultList

    def generate(self, resultList, n, comboList, openCount, closeCount):
        # are we done?
        if (openCount == n and closeCount == n):
            resultList.append(''.join(comboList))

        # can we open?
        if openCount < n:
            comboList.append('(')
            self.generate(resultList, n, comboList, openCount + 1, closeCount)
            comboList.pop()

        # can we close?
        if openCount > closeCount:
            comboList.append(')')
            self.generate(resultList, n, comboList, openCount, closeCount + 1)
            comboList.pop()
```

I think that `O(2^n)` makes the most sense. The depth of the recursion tree is `2*n`, because it stops once openCount and closeCount both equal n. The worst case is that each call to `generate()` calls itself twice, which would mean each recursion tree level doubles in size. `2*n` levels each doubling in size would mean `2^(2n)` nodes (each doing constant work). We drop the constant in front of n to get `O(2^n)` as the final runtime.

Am I thinking about it correctly?

Comment: Your code appears to be optimal, which means it will take O(Cn) results, where Cn is the nth [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). I don't remember the proof of that analysis, but you might be able to read up on the Catalan numbers and figure it out.

Comment: Link to the leetcode problem is broken. O(2^n) != O(2^(2n))

Answer (score 0):

You can not "drop" the "constant", because :
2^(2n) = (2^n)^2

Or even :
(2^2)^n
that equals to 4^n.

2^n and 4^n are not the same at all, you can try to draw the curves.

So it is `O(2^2n)`, according to me.

Comment: Big mathematical oversight on my part lol. Thanks!